# Master- Detail in JSF

Tags: hibernate, jsf, jpa, master-detail

I have doubts as to build this kind of relationship in jsf , when I have just a many to one such employer and employee, I use bidirectional relationship Collection with cascade and lazy , when I want to edit the employer , employers datatable I click on and go to the page editing , it carry the employer and their employees , which can modify the data of the employer and add or remove employees where I have a button that makes the save save the employer and employees in cascade.

```
@ Entity
{
 public class Employer

@ Id
private int id;

@ OneToMany ( mappedBy = " employer " , cascade = Cascade.TYPE.ALL )
private List <Employee> employees ;
...
}

@ Entity
public class Employee {

@ ManyToOne
Employer private employer ;
...
}


@ ManagedBean
private Class MyMB { 

private List <Employer> Employers ;
Employe private employer ;
private Employee employee ;

public void remove () {
employe.getEmployees.remove ( employee ) ;
}

public void add ( ) {
employer.getEmployees.add ( employee ) ;
}
public void save ( ) {
someService.persist ( employe ) ;
employes service.findAll = ();
}
}
```

acedito far that has not problems , my biggest question is when an entity has only one detail has
15 details eg I use unidirectional relationships ? Should carreger my collections separately?
I save the details separamente master ? was thinking of using tabs , each tab to a detail where would by
example the save and save the employer for employees

```
@ ManagedBean

 private Class MyMB {


private List <Employer> Employers ;
Employe private employer ;

private Employee employee ;
private List <Employees> employees ;



public void selectEmployer ( ) {
employer row.getData( ) ;
employees = employeeService.findEmployess ( employer ) ;
}


public void remove () {
employeeService.remove ( employee ) ;
employees = employeeService.findEmployess( employer ) ;

}

public void add ( ) {
employeeService.add ( employee ) ;
employees = employeeService.findEmployess ( employer ) ;
}

public void save ( ) {
someService.persist ( employe ) ;
employes  =  service.findAll();
}
}
```

this approach is correct ? is there any other better solution ? I am accepting suggestions .

Comment: I highly encourage you to have two different entities for your master and detail views. Map master entity against a DB table/view with minimal info, to be able to load it fastly. When you navigate to your detail view, then load the entity with the whole set of relations.

Comment: see this would help you (http://jsfspotlight.blogspot.com/2013/05/ejbjsf-master-detail-web-application-in_25.html)